# WebSQL - Lost in Transaction

Tags: javascript, android, web-applications, web-sql

I am developing a web-app using both WebSQL and IndexedDB. IndexedDB works well in browsers that support it, and my WebSQL implementation works in most browsers, however on Android javascript execution seems to be halting inside `db.transaction`.

Here is my code. I receive no console logs after "Initiating transaction..." (and no further JS seems to execute).

```
window.store.getFile = function( filename, callback ) {
    var db = window.store.websql.db;
    console.log('Initiating transaction...');
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        var filename2 = filename;
        var query = 'SELECT * FROM file WHERE filename = "'+filename+'"';
        console.log('Executing query:'+query);
        tx.executeSql(query, [], function(t, r) {
            if ( r.rows.length > 0 ) {
                var len = r.rows.length, i;
                for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    var filename = r.rows.item(i).filename;
                    var data = r.rows.item(i).data;
                    if ( callback ) callback( true, filename2, data );
                    break; // Break here as only one result should be returned
                }
            } else {
                if ( callback ) callback( false, filename2, null );
            }
        }, function(t, e) {
            console.log(e);
            if ( callback ) callback( false, filename2, null );
        });
    }, function(e) {
        console.log('Database transaction error: '+e);
        if ( callback ) callback( false, filename, null );
    }, function() {
        console.log('Transaction success');
    });
    console.log('Transaction initiated...');
};
```

(P.S. I also welcome any critique of my code...)

Comment: Oh, and I understand the sql injection potential of the query... I will ultimately be passing `filename` as a param to executeSql.

Comment: No receiving tx is strange. Have you successfully open the db?

Comment: Yes, the database is open, and the table is created correctly. Also, as I mentioned, this seems to work just fine on other browsers too. Only having the issue on Android (stock browser, Chrome and Dolphin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are chasing is probably raised on the db level error handler (passed in openDatabase). Some android phones just don't accept null or undefined for that error handler the the symptoms are what you described. No error, no success just nothing...

Also: your success block should be in try/catch to prevent that error to bubble up automatically.

Also: note that the return value to success handler (false/true) will determine what happens when an error is thrown (rollback or just error without rollback).

Comment: I shall definitely accept this answer, as all indicators were pointing in this direction. I wasn't able to confirm it, but it went away after I reworked some of this code (including the openDatabase error handlers).

It was certainly a curious issue as no errors were thrown on the Android's console log, and it was odd that is had continued executing other Javascript up until this point.

My suspicion would be that some part of the openDatabase code was deferred until the transaction was established, which is when things went funky.

Thanks for giving me a good idea of where to look!!